# Access denied to database with phpunit in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have an application that is running in a server. The app is working and I can do everything that I wish. Now, I want to test with phpunit. My configuration files are:

The .env:

```
APP_ENV=local
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_KEY=KEY
APP_URL=http://localhost/

DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=db
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=pwd

CACHE_DRIVER=file
SESSION_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_DRIVER=sync
```

My Database.php:

```
'connections' => [

        'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1:3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'db'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'pwd'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => false,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
(...)
```

And my phpunit.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit backupGlobals="false"
         backupStaticAttributes="false"
         bootstrap="bootstrap/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
         convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
         convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
         convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
         processIsolation="false"
         stopOnFailure="false">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Application Test Suite">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <filter>
        <whitelist processUncoveredFilesFromWhitelist="true">
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
            <exclude>
                <file>./app/Http/routes.php</file>
            </exclude>
        </whitelist>
    </filter>
    <php>
        <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

The test case class is the created by default by Laravel and I have a test that is:

```
public function testBasicExample()
    {        
        $this->visit('/')
             ->see('CSM Portal');

    }
```

**So, the page that I want to visit makes a count(*) to a database. 
My database is in the same server as the application. And I access them from my computer to the server.
I open a cmd inside the project folder inside the server and run the command:**

> "vendor/bin/phpunit"

but I get this error:

> Caused by PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

So, what am I doing wrong with my code? The credentials are correct, I am sure, because they are the same that I use to access the app with the client and it works. I checked in phpmyadmin to.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are u using Homestead? is the database running on the same machine as your application?

Comment: @YoramdeLangen I am not using Homestead and the database is on the same machine as the application

Comment: Note, you shouldn't be using a root password from your application. Create a separate web user account and use that instead.

Comment: @JohnJoseph I created a new user, I gave him all permissions, still the same error (access denied)

Comment: I deleted the "vendor" folder inside my project!
Then I run `composer update` command that creates again the folder and its working. Unbeliveable how I spent so much time with this -_-
Thanks for the answers

Answer (score 7):

You application environment when running PhpUnit is `testing` (as set in `<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>`)

Therefore, you need another `.env` file called `.env.testing` which contains your test environment settings.

Answer (score -1):

I deleted the "vendor" folder inside my project! Then I run composer update command that creates again the folder and its working. Unbeliveable how I spent so much time with this -_-